# Network drive disconnects randomly

Tags: networking, hard-drive, mapped-drive

I have an application that a lot of users use. The users are spread on a network and all the data used by the application is stored on a network drive. The application reads the data from the drive, process it then saves it back to the drive. Multiple users work at the same time. Sometimes it happens that the network drive disconnects exactly during a save, resulting in files cut in half. I've implemented a backup feature so we always lose a maximum of 15 minutes of work. But even that is a lot. Is it possible to have continuous connection?

What could be the problem if a network hard drive disconnects randomly? The internet connection is always there. I see red X:es on the folders and I can't open them. I can reach the internet just fine. After some time, the hard drive is connected again, for no apparent reason.

Anyone have a clue why this might happen? It happens more often when I'm on wifi compared to connected by wire. But the internet connection is always there.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This normally occurs because the resource is idle for a period. If configured properly, re-connection is almost immediate.  Try this:   NET USE  t: /delete for all drives "t".   Restart and connect your drives.   Any improvement?

Comment: Does this behave differently if you use the UNC path instead of a mapped network drive?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Not sure what you mean. I'm using the UNC path to add the drive in windows explorer. In the code, I'm using the drive letter. Like "Open G:\Data\File.txt For Output" etc. etc.

Comment: I mean simply don't use the drive letter and access directly.  That mapped drive letter is another layer.